# Analyze data by query in Firebird

Tags: sql, pivot-table, firebird

I need to create a Analyze data table to put in listview in c#. This is my query:

```
    SELECT CL.CLIENT_CODE, CL.CLIENT_NAME, 
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 1, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH1,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 2, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH2,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 3, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH3,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 4, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH4,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 5, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH5,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 6, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH6,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 7, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH7,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 8, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH8,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 9, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH9,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 10, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH10,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 11, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH11,
    IIF (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED) = 12, COUNT(CL.CLIENT_CODE), '') AS MONTH12
    FROM CLIENTS CL INNER JOIN CJOBS J ON (CL.CLIENT_ID = J.CLIENT_ID)
    GROUP BY CL.CLIENT_CODE, CL.CLIENT_NAME, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM J.CJOB_ASSIGNED)
```

And result of this query, data were analyzed by the month, but they were not all in a row for each client that split into many different data rows:
[image: Result Table]

The results as I wish 
[image: Wish Table]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get separate rows per month, is because that is what you asked for. You are grouping by month, so each month has its own row.

To get the result you want you need to transform the query to first get the counts you want per month and client, and only then 'pivot' those months to columns per month.

For the first part you need a query like:

```sql
select client_id, extract(month from cjob_assigned), count(*) 
from cjobs
group by client_id, extract(month from cjob_assigned)
```

Now to transform this to a pivot table with one row per client and a column per month, you'll need to execute this query 12x per client. To make this easier we can use a [common table expression](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-cte), so we don't have to repeat the whole select each time (as a simplification: a CTE can be seen as an inline view).

The final query then becomes:

```sql
with jcm (client_id, monthnr, jobcount) as (
    select client_id, extract(month from cjob_assigned), count(*)
    from cjobs
    group by client_id, extract(month from cjob_assigned)
)
select client_code, client_name,
  (select jobcount from jcm where jcm.client_id = clients.client_id and jcm.monthnr = 1) as month1,
  (select jobcount from jcm where jcm.client_id = clients.client_id and jcm.monthnr = 2) as month2,
  -- ... add months 3 - 11
  (select jobcount from jcm where jcm.client_id = clients.client_id and jcm.monthnr = 12) as month12
from clients
```

BTW: You might want to consider including year as well (although that does make things a bit more complex).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very well. But now, I am trying sum all data of 12 month column. This is a flaw in my question. I hope to get your help again. Thank you again for you help.

Comment: @FoxVĩnhTâm Just add another column with `(select sum(jobcount) from jcm where jcm.client_id = clients.client_id) as total`

Comment: Although I don't really understand this struct, I've customized it to suit my intentions. I am going to try to research this structure because it really useful. Thank you again. Cheers.